# StrongLoop Client extending User Model Built-in log in error

Tags: acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

Has anyone experienced extending the built-in model "user" in StrongLoop via Client?

The thing is, I can't skip the verification for the newly created clients. I have declared the Client with the option "emailVerificationRequired": false, but still I can't log in.

Error:

> error: Object code: "LOGIN_FAILED_EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED" message: "login
>   failed as the email has not been verified" name: "Error" stack:
>   "Error: login failed as the email has not been verified↵    at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\loopback-getting-started\node_modules\loopback\common\models\user.js:248:21↵
>   at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\loopback-getting-started\node_modules\loopback\common\models\user.js:312:9"
>   status: 401 statusCode: 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you  don't want  email verification PUT below code in
>   model-config.json

```
"user": {
"dataSource": "YOUR DATASOURCE",
"public": true,
"options": {
  "emailVerificationRequired": false
},
"$promise": {},
"$resolved": true}
```

> And other thing is, you manually stop verification doing below logic. 
>   For example if users created by Admin.

```
  user.beforeRemote('create' ,function(ctx, modelInstance, next)
  {

      if(ctx.req.query.key == "admin") // if users created by Admin.
      {
        ctx.args.data.emailVerified = 1;
      }

      next();
  });
```

**IN afterRemote**

```
user.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {


              if(!user.emailVerified)
                {

                    console.log('> user.afterRemote triggered');
                    var options = {
                      type: 'email',
                      to: user.email,
                      from: 'youremail,
                      subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
                      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
                      redirect: '/verified',
                      user: user
                    };

                    user.verify(options, function(err, response) {
                      if (err) return next(err);

                      context.res.render('response', {
                        title: 'Signed up successfully',
                        content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link ' +
                            'before logging in.',
                        redirectTo: '/',
                        redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
                      });
                    });

                }
                else
                {

                  next();
                }

          });
```

Comment: Dude, you are a life-saver! Thanks a lot! Didn't realize that it has the configuration of my model on the model-config.json file XD